# Delete unused webpack chunked files

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm looking for information on how to delete old webpack chunked files. Here is my current webpack configuration:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  debug: false,
  outputPathinfo: true,
  displayErrorDetails: true,
  context: __dirname,
  entry: {
    common: ['./src/common.coffee'],
    a: './src/a.cjsx',
    b: './src/b.cjsx'
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name]-[chunkhash].js',
    chunkFileName: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'js')
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('common', 'common-[chunkhash].js'),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: { warnings: false }
    })
  ],
  module: {
    preLoaders: [
      {
        test: /\.coffee$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'coffeelint-loader'
      }
    ],
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.coffee/, loader: 'coffee' },
      { test: /\.cjsx$/, loaders: ['coffee', 'cjsx'] },
      { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'jsx-loader?harmony' }
    ]
  }
}
```

If I am running `$(npm bin)/webpack --config webpack.js --watch` and make changes to `a.cjsx`, it compiles a newer version of that file with a new chunkedhash. However, the old one remains and I'd like it to be deleted right away.

1. How can I delete the old version of the chunked file?
2. Is there a way for me to hook into an after callback once watch finishes compiling?

Answer (score 23):

There is a [clean-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/johnagan/clean-webpack-plugin) for those purposes, or you can write a simple `bash` script for `npm`:

```
 "scripts": {
    "build": "rm -r dist/* && webpack -p",
    "clean": "rm -r dist/*"
  }
```

Comment: The author means how to delete  old `chunk` with `hash` when use `--watch` cli option .

Comment: Unfortunately, clean-webpack-plugin does work with `webpack --watch` (it will clean once, after that multiple versions of the same file will start to pile up each time it's changed) ; probably because it doesn't really know which chunks are obsolete.

Comment: Thanks for plan B - saved me hours of frustrating in trying not to get clean-webpack-plugin to delete stuff twice.

Comment: @klewis you can use 'webpack-clean-obsolete-chunks' to remove unused chunk files

Answer (score 15):

Here is the [`webpack-clean-obsolete-chunks`](https://github.com/GProst/webpack-clean-obsolete-chunks) plugin, which do what you want. It searches for all updated chunks and deletes obsolete files after each `webpack` compilation.

Comment: for some reasons it does nothing

Comment: Its for `watch` only

Answer (score 9):

Since Webpack 5.20.0 you can use [`output.clean`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputclean) option

Comment: Yekes! be warned, I almost cleaned out my entire project with his. Luckily I was able to recover the deleted files through my cloud service...

Answer (score 7):

### The answer

I've decided to write an answer because others - although trying to answer the question directly - overlooked the most important part in my opinion.

*And the most important part is*: you shouldn't be doing it this way. Using `[hash]` placeholders in your development setup cause many headaches with other tooling (phpstorm's path autocomplete in symfony plugin for example). Also it's poor for webpack's incremental compilation performance and thus is not recommended by official webpack docs ([reference](https://webpack.js.org/guides/build-performance/#avoid-production-specific-tooling)).

*So for future readers*: just keep it simple for development config - define your `filename` as `[name].js` and move on.

### Edit

There seems to be a confusion about what to do with the old chunk-files on the production server. Well, you don't do anything. Once a version is deployed it shouldn't be ever changed. You just keep creating new versions when deploying and keep previous as a backup. Why?

Because you want you're rollback to be reliable and for it to be possible your rollback needs to be extremely simple and atomic. If your rollback procedure is doing anything more than switching a symlink, rerouting to previous container (or similar simple operation) you're probably™ going to end up in trouble.

Rollback isn't a process of "re-deploying" the application again, but now to the previous version. It's a process of "un-doing" the deployment. So doing a `git checkout` to the previous version followed by a `npm build --but-please-be-hurry --and-im-begging-you-dont-fail` while your production app is hanging there, completely exploded doesn't cut here.

Rebuilding a previous version of the application - just like the deployment - may fail for many reasons. That's why a rollback should be switching/rerouting back to the exact same version-build that is proven to be working. Not `==`-the-same, 100% `===`-the-same. That's why you need to keep your previous version around, because that's the `===`-same. A "regenerated" one is - in best case scenario - only `==`-the-same, and so it is not proven to be working, only assumed.

And no, no amount of CI, staging environments or whatever will give you a guaranteed successful deployment. Part of doing it the right way is to be prepared for when things go wrong. And things *will* go wrong. Hopefully only from time to time, but still.

*Of course once you have 3, 5 or `<put-your-number-here>` versions backed up you may start to remove the oldest ones as you probably won't ever need more than 3.*

Comment: the right answer. I think some might just be confused about the [hash] and don't realize you can conditionally use them depending on whether you are in development or production.

Comment: And how to clean the chunk files in production builds? All old chunk files remain.

Comment: Well, the issue seems bigger in prod than in dev. Locally, I can just delete the folder every now and then without risk. On the server this might cause downtime and unexpected behavior etc. while the new bundle is being generated

Comment: @mousetail in prod it shouldn't be a concern at all - do your self a favor and set up an automated deployment pipeline where the new version is built in the background (either in a new directory, in a new docker container, or whatever) and once finished trffic gets rerouted to the newest version (either by switching a symlink or redirecting on the load balancer, or whatever). No downtime and no old files, as the older versions will be destroyed after some time. For the sake of simplicity i would recommend the symlink approach but it's a matter of preference and requirements.

Comment: @mousetail with the symlink approach you could easily do it by hand, but it get's tedious and is error prone. That's why i recommend automated solution, and there's plenty of such deployment toolkits available on the github.

Comment: @plunnticiam in that case, new chunk files will be generated from the rolled back source code. You will rollback some commits and you won't rebuild? That would be a disaster mistake. Chunk files shouldn't be deleted immediately not because in a case of rollback, but because there may be clients still using them (*haven't refreshed the page for an SPA*). So, chunk files should be deleted but not immediately, but after a while, like an automated clean job.

Comment: @ChristosLytras nope: a version - once built - shouldn't be ever modified, because you need to restore it as a whole in an atomic manner (like switching a symlink - just one operation that in most cases is impossible to go wrong) when you do a rollback. Your rollback procedure needs to be reliable - switching a symlink is, while rebuilding the whole app after checking back it's previous version is not. What if along the way you've broken (also) your build pipeline somehow and didn't know? Now you're app exploded, and you can't do a rollback because your build pipeline isn't working.

Comment: @ChristosLytras of course it all depends, if your project isn't mission critical and no one is loosing a lot of money every second of it's downtime you may get away with doing it your way. But in most cases - in professional environment - it is not acceptable. And about the old hashes. They're not a problem because once the new version is built you're switching a symlink pointing to your domain's "public_html" directory to the directory with the new version, so all the old files aren't accessible from outside anymore. You're just keeping few of your last versions on the server, just in case.

Comment: @plunnticiam I'm not talking about modifications, I am talking about deleting old chunk files. There is nothing reliable in keeping old chunk files around just in order to rollback them if needed. You put a lot of invalid *"ifs"* in your arguments like broken CI, which of course may happen, but think again.. if everything goes wrong, then the people that made the deployment system are not reliable... If rebuilding your production application is getting your *mission critical project* down, then you're doing something very wrong with the building deploying process.

Comment: @plunnticiam If you have any experience using CI, then you'll know that there are many methods to keep the endpoint online while there is a rebuild running and of course that is only for very large projects. Also, if you keep the chunk hashes to a version control then again you doing a big mistake; hashes are to be generated (*in development or production*) and **NOT** to be kept *just in case* are going to be needed.

Comment: @ChristosLytras please see my updated answer. Also keep in mind this is not something i've invented. That's how many - or maybe most - of the big boys do it (of course it gets more complicated as they have more complicated setups, but the idea is more or less the same). If you're still not convinced and/or you know better. Well, fine. Keep doing it your way and be happy. SO isn't a good place for long discussions anyway, so good luck :)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this pull request:
https://github.com/johnagan/clean-webpack-plugin/pull/32/files

Open raw file view and copy it to index.js of clean webpack plugin.
Remember about config flag -> watch: true

Answer (score 1):

I have solved that problem by adding below in `webpack.config.js`

```
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');    
{
  ... your configs ...
  plugins: [new CleanWebpackPlugin()]
}
```

Comment: More detail on this can be found in the official docs https://webpack.js.org/guides/output-management/#cleaning-up-the-dist-folder

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem № 1 by using [remove-files-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/Amaimersion/remove-files-webpack-plugin).

Use this plugin like this:

```js
plugins: [
  new RemovePlugin({
    watch: {
      test: [
        {
          folder: './js',
          method: (absPath) => new RegExp(/(.*)-([^-\\\/]+)\.js/).test(absPath)
        }
      ]
    }
  })
]
```

In "watch" mode (not normal compilation!) it grabs all files from `./js` folder and tests them with this regular expression `/(.*)-([^-\\\/]+)\.js/`. Analyze this regular expression on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/LIP6iJ/2) (unit tests are included) if you have problems with understanding.

Note: i'm the creator of this plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like webpack@5.20.0+ has built-in support for this https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputclean. I use `[chunkhash]` in my chunk filenames and they get cleared out if I stop comment out dynamic imports and added back in if I uncomment them.

Answer (score 1):

my case: webpack 5 + multipage application + themes.css via entry points

solution: https://github.com/webdiscus/webpack-remove-empty-scripts

this plugins don't work with webpack 5 entry points or with MiniCssExtractPlugin:

[webpack-fix-style-only-entries](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-fix-style-only-entries),
[webpack-extraneous-file-cleanup-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-extraneous-file-cleanup-plugin),
[webpack-remove-empty-js-chunks-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-remove-empty-js-chunks-plugin),
[webpack-delete-no-js-entries-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-delete-no-js-entries-plugin).

my `webpack.config.js`:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const RemoveEmptyScriptsPlugin = require('webpack-remove-empty-scripts');

const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
const isDev = !isProd;

const PAGES = ['app', 'help'];

const getThemes = (themePath, alias) => {
  let themes = {};
  const longPath = './' + alias + '/' + themePath;
  fs.readdirSync(longPath).forEach(function(fileName) {
    const fileNameWithPath = path.join(themePath, fileName);
    const fileNameWithLongPath = path.join(longPath, fileName);

    const stat = fs.lstatSync(fileNameWithLongPath);
    if (stat.isDirectory()) return;
    if (!/\.scss$/.test(fileName)) return;

    const nameWithoutExt = path.basename(fileName, '.scss');
    themes[nameWithoutExt] = ['./' + fileNameWithPath];
  });
  console.log(themes);
  return themes;
};

const themes = getThemes('scss/themes', 'src');

const getFilename = (filename, ext) => {
  let name = filename == 'index' ? 'bundle' : filename;
  const isTheme = (ext == 'css' && name.startsWith('theme')) ? true : false;
  const needHash = (isDev || isTheme) ? false : true;
  return needHash ? name +`.[fullhash].` + ext : name+'.'+ext;
};

const getCSSDirname = filename => {
  const isTheme = filename.startsWith('theme');
  return !isTheme? '/css/' : '/css/theme/';
};

const getHTMLWebpackPlugins = arr => {
  // this function config multipages names and add to html-pages
  // inside <head> tag our themes via tag <link rel="stylesheet" href="....css" ...>
  // and return array of HTMLWebpackPlugins
};

module.exports = {
// ... //
  entry: {
    // mutipage:
    app:  ['./index.js', './scss/app.scss'], 
    help: ['./help.js', './scss/help.scss'],
    // multitheme:
    ...themes,
  },
  optimization: {
    removeEmptyChunks: true, // not work!!!
  },
  // ... //
  plugins: [
    // ... //
    ...getHTMLWebpackPlugins(PAGES),
    new RemoveEmptyScriptsPlugin({
      ignore:  PAGES,
      enabled: isDev === false,
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: pathdata => {
        return getCSSDirname(pathdata.chunk.name) + getFilename(pathdata.chunk.name, 'css');
      },
      chunkFilename: isDev ? '[id].css' : '[id].[contenthash].css',
    }),
  ],
};
```

my src files:

```
[src]:
 - index.js
 - index.html
 - help.js
 - help.html
 - [scss]:
 - - app.scss
 - - help.scss
 - - [themes]:
 - - - light.scss
 - - - dark.scss
 - - - blue.scss
```

after build:

```
[dist]:
 - app.js
 - index.html
 - help$hash.js
 - help$hash.html
 - [css]:
 - - app$hash.css
 - - help$hash.css
 - - [themes]:
 - - - light.css
 - - - dark.css
 - - - blue.css
```

Answer (score 0):

For Windows users

```json
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npm run clean && webpack --mode production",
    "clean": "del /f /s /q dist 1>nul"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had to stop my server and run `yarn serve` again

Answer (score 0):

clean-webpack-plugin is evil. I strongly do not recommend using it

I remove all unused chunks after emit using this script.

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

mix.webpackConfig({
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  output: {
    chunkFilename: 'static/ui/js/chunks/[hash][name].js',
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        vendors: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          chunks: 'async',
          idHint: 'vendor'
        }
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    { // Removing unused chunks after emit
      apply: (compiler) => {
        // Called after emitting assets to output directory
        compiler.hooks.afterEmit.tap('AfterEmitPlugin', (compilation) => {
          const CHUNKS_FOLDER = 'static/ui/js/chunks/';
          // List of used chunks
          const chunks = compilation.chunks.map(
            chunk => chunk.files[0]
          ).filter(
            chunk => chunk.startsWith(CHUNKS_FOLDER)
          ).map(
            chunk => chunk.slice(CHUNKS_FOLDER.length)
          )

          // Substring to exclude used chunks
          const chunksExcludingSubstr = chunks.map(
            chunk => `-not -name ${chunk}`
          ).join(' ')

          exec(
            `find ${CHUNKS_FOLDER} -type f ${chunksExcludingSubstr} -delete`,
            (err, stdout, stderr) => 
            {
              if (stderr) process.stderr.write(stderr);
            }
          );
        });
      }
    }
  ]
})
```